# "How can adventurers cover long distances quickly within the dungeon?"

Tags: dungeons

I have been writing a novel, 'The Dungeon,' for a while now (it's been six months already). I've tried to plan almost everything, but there's still a lot before my masterpiece is complete. So, my question is, how can adventurers cover long distances within the dungeon quickly? I find it illogical considering the length of the distance and the numerous obstacles. This would make the dungeon extremely challenging to navigate, leading adventurers to take weeks to explore it.

This introduces many plot twists, such as how to survive during that period or what they can do if they lose their supplies mid-journey. Sorry for digressing, but my real question is how to measure the time the adventurers will spend inside the dungeon, considering all possibilities.

I've already done that, where I measured the time explorers and adventurers are likely to take inside the dungeon. However, I want other ideas that I might have overlooked. So, I'll show you my initial plan for measuring the duration:

First, I needed to know the area of my dungeon. I divided the first floor into five main sections (Note: the dungeon is extremely large, so don't be surprised by what I'm about to mention). The first floor is a coastal cave with complex and varied environments, from intricate cave networks to hidden ruins within these caves. The first floor consists of five main regions, each composed of cave bubbles - semi-circular spaces connected by dark cave passages. These cave bubbles contain various and diverse environments, including large, small, and hidden bubbles inaccessible to adventurers.

I've already defined the types of environments and regions for each bubble, and each bubble has a specified area. The first floor consists of 100 cave bubbles with different dimensions, covering an area of up to 1225 km/761 miles. These cave bubbles are divided into four different sections, spread across the entire first floor, and composed of:

1. Large Cave Bubbles: These are distinct cave bubbles with unique environments, including ruins in their areas, stretching for 25 km. There are 25 such bubbles on the first floor.
2. Small Cave Bubbles: These are similar cave bubbles appearing in groups with similar environments, extending for 5 km. There are 60 of them on the first floor.
3. Treasure Cave Bubbles: These are cave bubbles with distinctive environments, full of life and treasures. They are semi-hidden from adventurers' view, stretching for 40 km. There are only five of them on the first floor.
4. Breeding Cave Bubbles: These are cave bubbles housing nests and breeding grounds for monsters, serving as their homes, extending for 10 km. There are ten such bubbles on the first floor.

So, with this area, I conducted several calculations, but I've already forgotten them. I'll provide a simplified calculation that requires the adventurer not to rest:

If a person walks at a speed of 5 kilometers per hour and walks for 12 hours a day, we can calculate the distance they cover in a day in kilometers:

(5 km/h \times 12 h = 60 km/day.)

Now, to calculate the time it would take to cover 699 miles, we can convert miles to kilometers using the known conversion rate (1 mile is approximately equal to 1.60934 kilometers):

(699 miles \times 1.60934 km/mile \approx 1,122.78 km.)

Then we divide this distance by the distance covered in a day:

(1,122.78 km ÷ 60 km/day \approx 18.71 days.)

So, the person would take about 18.71 days to cover a distance of 699 miles when walking 12 hours a day at a speed of 5 kilometers per hour. The answer can be rounded to approximately 19 days.

I had performed many other calculations, such as how much time monsters would delay them in battles and the number of hours of rest, considering the needs of an ordinary person. With all these factors, the duration for the adventurer to traverse the first floor exceeded several months. Keep in mind that the previous calculation only applies if the adventurer can walk in a straight line without interruption for 12 continuous hours a day.

For reference, here's a picture of the dungeon :

[image: Picture of the dungeon]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I was asking about the factors that affect adventurers traversing inside dungeons, causing them delays compared to monsters and traps - I mean, such as deep terrains, the dungeon's climate, and others."

Comment: You're describing the area in linear miles, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and haven't described the layout or where the adventurers are actually trying to go. 100 25km-wide cave bubbles laid end will be a continent-spanning 2500km, but laid out in a 10x10 grid, nothing is more than 1/10th that distance away. It's not clear why you need such immense distances to begin with if the plan is for the adventurers to rapidly skip most of the rooms anyhow. And anyway, you describe it as an *exploration* mission, suggesting the goal is catalogue each room and *not* skip along rapidly.

Comment: "Yes, those pulleys are not accurate, as I mentioned; they are already old. However, I included them because I couldn't find the modified pulleys. In short, it will take the adventurer a few months to surpass the first floor.

Also, regarding the area, I have also adjusted it. What I want is to simulate a semi-realistic fantasy world, especially the part related to the dungeon.

In my novel, adventurers will take a lot of time to overcome the first floor, and I don't intend to make it easy for them to escape from the floor. Therefore, many adventurers explore various ways of the dungeon

Comment: dungeon with different exits.

I don't think I mentioned it, but there are five endings on the first floor for each region, each with its own unique ending, so as not to make the floor too long for the adventurers."

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding. Per the [help], giving your own answer and asking for more is prohibited. Open-ended questions that lead to all answers having equal value are prohibited and brainstorming is discouraged. Further, questions about character/group/organizational choices are prohibited. Writers frequently start the next chapter days/weeks/months/years later because the intervening time isn't relevant to the story and simply had to pass to get to the next circumstance. How you rationalize that jump in presented time isn't worldbuilding.

Comment: Could you kindly remove the quotes around everything you say? It makes me feel like you're a bot, and your programmer didn't bother with proper formatting.

Comment: @BlackShadow - Walking a consistent 5 kph is *extremely* optimistic. Especially for 12 hours. I can comfortably walk at 6 kph on a nice flat surface, but if I go out into the Bush on a Hunt (which is going to be similar to the conditions within a Cave) - my average pace is about half that - 2-3 kph. Distance travelled per day is more likely going to be 30 Km.

Comment: Agree with @TheDemonLord comment - sustained 5 km/hr is not plausible except on well-formed road with no obstacles and is the speed of a forced march, not patrolling.  Back in my infantry days we did 15 km forced marches with full gear as part of a combat fitness test, never 60 km.  The pace is too rapid to be stealthy or keeping a good watch for ambushes.  For reference, as part of training for an upcoming ultra I did 55 km with a 7 kg pack a few weeks back and was pretty wiped out for the next day or so - adventurers will have much more than 7 kg of gear each.

Comment: Standard unit movement speed for infantry is around 30 miles per day, and this presumes some kind of paved roadway. Adventurers might do better if they push themselves, but it isn't sustainable.

Comment: Apologies, but I have to VTC: Needs details or clarity. This question appears to be reducible to "what would be the rate of travel across undefined terrain?" OP even states that there are dozens of unique environments, and provides a visual example of one that would be impassable without a boat. The issue is further complicated by a title that seems to ask for methods of fast-travel, as evidenced by the presented answers. This question isn't answerable without complete terrain details.

Comment: Salam Black Shadow! You should have the big picture of how your question was received, now we can try to improve it without invalidating existing answers. You'll notice that you actually (in reality) asked 2 questions, even though people answered only your title question ("how can they travel so fast?"). You should remove the other question : it lies in the 2nd and 3rd paragraph : "How much time do my travelers need to travel from one place to another?". Increasing your adventurer's speed is not the same as calculating their speed. This might be just because of your translation tool ^^.

Comment: If you focus on how can you make them go faster, I think you can then also skip (ie. remove/delete) the part where you calculate their theoretical walking speed : the part where you say they walk at 5km/h for 12h. Just keep the last paragraph ("*I had performed many other calculations... [...] ...the duration for the adventurer to traverse the first floor exceeded several months.*") and end it with your title question, just rephrased : "*How can I make them traverse the first floor in much less time than walking?*". Doing this should make your question a viable candidate for reopening :).

Comment: General tech level available? How extensive are the navigable water ways,the Maritime highway is key due to cost difference of transport. rivers are a factor of 5 cheaper then land assuming good land roads. Food? About 1Kg day/per person. Are they pillaging, conjuring food or bringing food with them from the entrance?

Answer (score 7):

### Do as the Romans do

A sheltered place this big that contains *ruins* is a place that used to house a society. That society was confronted by the same travel challenges. There may be remnants of their solution that still function, or can be repaired or reactivated.

Perhaps there is a network of teleportation booths that still partially works. Maybe there is a kind of train whose tracks cling to the shadowy ceiling and which makes stops at a few points of interest. Maybe there are long swaths of magical sand that work like the horizontal conveyor belts in airports (or the "highways" in *Caves of Steel*), connecting the different ruins.

The central fact of every "ancient world" is that today's problems are not new, and that the ancients' solutions are still applicable in some way if only you can locate, identify, and deploy them.

Ruins are uninteresting if they contain only debris.

Answer (score 5):

**Remember the game [Snakes and Ladders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_ladders)?**

There are underground rivers. These can be "ridden" from one place to another, even covering long distances, be that by boat (canoe) or free-swimming.

The one rule is: the destination point must be slightly lower than the start.

The journey can be accomplished by taking the "river" down, the return-journey necessitates climbing stairs or scaling a slope or rockface, either at the start of the journey, or the end-point. Either way water runs downhill is the rule. Perhaps there are interruptions part way through the journey, where the boat needs to be hauled up some slope to another waypoint, perhaps there is mechanical assistance at some places, perhaps there are donkeys/ponies/camels for-hire for help with this.
See [Flume Ride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_flume_(ride)) for details of the sort of thing I mean.

These can be treacherous: Some have [white-water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewater) which may spill travellers from a boat and smash them to pieces on rocks, some pass through underground passages with no air. Perhaps some passages take travellers where they are never heard from again. Perhaps some passages have run dry, necessitating a long walk.

As a story-device, there is great flexibility in what can happen.

Comment: "Yes, as mentioned, adventurers can ride deep water channels or flowing rivers to expedite the journey, but I don't believe cautious adventurers would resort to such a risky measure.

Considering the potential dangers I mentioned, such as collisions, crashes, or other risks like dangerous monsters lurking beneath the river, from the adventurers' perspective, such a gamble is not convincing (risks to your life for some extra time). However, there are still those who indulge in such madness."

Comment: Please check the body of your question, there is no mention of water. Perhaps you meant to include that paragraph, but missed it out.

Comment: "It wasn't mentioned in the question, but it's part of the plan or the specific environment in the dungeon. There is an image below the question, which is an approximate illustration of the dungeon.

As mentioned in the question, the cave environment is a coastal one, meaning there are water channels and pools in the dungeon. It's my mistake that I didn't add more details."

Comment: That's ok. We all make errors. For my part, I couldn't even tell that there was water in the image, I assumed some sort of blue sand especially considering the perspective shows it sloping. There are also visually impaired (and blind) readers of our site, so it's important to ensure that all the details are written as well as in an image.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just too big for a group of people to realistically walk, you might have to try some other things, like:

- Finding another method of travelling.
- Making the dungeon smaller/easier (not recommended).

I'd suggest finding another travel method. Having something like a vehicle or a fast animal could reduce the time the people need to explore, while not altering the environment as much. You could also have some item that increases the speed of the traveller.

If this is not possible, you might have to change the actual dungeon by either reducing the amount of enemies or just making it smaller. I do think this isn't the best option, so you should only use this as a last resort.

I hope this can help you!

Comment: "Yes, that's what I was thinking. Adventurers attempt to explore new ways to traverse the dungeon, even though they often fail."

Answer (score 1):

### Saddle the locals

Any area this large is likely to become home to all kinds of creatures, not just monsters. Some of those creatures may even be species your party is familiar with from the world above.

If the party is confronted by such an immense, trackless wilderness, and they stumble across an animal that is either recognized as a mount or looks like it could serve as one, they will at least consider ways to ride it. Besides the obvious reason, another is that the local animals have developed instincts for surviving in this area -- they recognize predators, the different kinds of terrain, which plants and water sources are safe, etc. The animal knows how to survive here and they can follow its lead.

Some mounts can fly, or climb, or swim. If magic is a thing, some mounts may have magical abilities like teleportation or invisibility, that will neutralize the natural challenges that would otherwise slow a traveler down. Likely, the specifics of their natural movement is a big part of how they survive in a place that also contains monsters.

I imagine a long, silken mustachipede trundling amiably out of the underbrush to nuzzle whoever smells like coconut oil, then flapping its big waxy wings excitedly, showering the astonished party in potato crumbs. "Oi!" says somebody, "this fella smells like sour cream and onion!" Instant friendship.